# Image saves to server but doesn't appear in browser when using header()

Tags: php, image, post, http-headers

I've set up jCrop so that users on my site can crop and save (download) images. I'm near the end now however I've hit a wall. I've got the code set up (see below) and when I comment out the `header()` line everything works as intended, the cropped image is saved to the server and I can download it from there.

The problem is that when I include the header and broken image is returned and I'm really not sure why. If anyone could help I would be most grateful

```
<?php
//$_POST['src'] = http://example.com/example.jpg
$image_url = $_POST['src'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$targ_w = $_POST['w']; $targ_h = $_POST['h'];

$image = imagecreatefromstring( $data );
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

if ( !$image )
    exit( 'No valid image' );

$path = '/home/hostname/public_html/'.time().'-image.jpg';

imagecopyresampled( $dst_r, $image, 0, 0, $_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $targ_w, $targ_h, $_POST['w'], $_POST['h'] );

//header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );

imagejpeg( $dst_r, $path, 100 );

imagedestroy( $dst_r );
//unlink( $path );
exit;
?>
```

Currently as the code stands the image is saved in the root of the site. If I uncomment the `unlink()` the image is deleted from the directory (which is intended). If I uncomment the `header()` line then a page is returned containing a broken image with the src matching the page url.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [the documentation](http://php.net/imagejpeg) specifies, the second argument of `imagejpeg` should be `NULL` if you want to output the image directly.

Try changing `imagejpeg( $dst_r, $path, 100 );` to `imagejpeg( $dst_r, NULL, 100 );`.

Edit: this also saves you from using `unlink`, since no file is made.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention that I have tried this too but unfortunately the results are the same. If I do this without the header I get a lot of random code however at the start there is what looks like a comment of some sort `{!-- ra:0000000031f43c5400000000190dd210 --}` I'm not sure if that is part of the image or not?

Comment: You should use the header if you want to see the image itself. Without specifying a different Content-Type header, PHP usually assumes the content type is text/html.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was essentially rendering the image as HTML code hence why it was a mess? It just seemed strange as the code snippet above looks "readable" compared to the rest so I wasn't sure if it was an error of sorts. I've also tried adding `header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );` and `header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );` to get the file to save but it returns a file with no extension.

Comment: I've just tried the following: `header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.jpg"');` but again it outputs image.jpg as a corrupt image. Does the path need to be an absolute server path or can it be a url?

Comment: Change the content type to what it actually is.

Comment: Unfortunately no success there. It must be bringing in something correctly though as if I do a small crop the file size is smaller than when I do a large crop.

Comment: And it did work correctly when saving the image to the disk with `imagejpeg`?

Comment: Yup. That's what's confusing me. If it was corrupt at that point then it would at least be a consistent issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61399/discussion-between-kieran-mcclung-and-phantom).

Comment: This helped out a great deal and the `$path` change is a nice improvement. It's that pesky `{!-- ra:0000000031f43c5400000000190dd210 --}`